# uploading list of object, where object will be having file and metadata field in FastAPI

Tags: python, api, file-upload, fastapi, starlette

In my fastAPI application, i am defining a post api, where i have to receive files and its metadata from frontend. I will be receiving list of dictionary(or object) where dictionary will be having two field file and metadata. But i am getting error unprocessable entity.

Below is my python code

```
class FileItem(BaseModel):
    file: UploadFile = File(...)
    filetype: str = Form(...)

class FileItems(BaseModel):
    payload:list[FileItem]

@router.post("/testing/processfiles")
async def process_files(file_items: FileItems):
    for item in file_items:
        file = item.file
        filetype = item.filetype
        print(file,filetype)
    return {"message": "Files and strings processed successfully"}
```

in swaggerUI the request body is of application/json instead of multipart/form-data.

Request body

> {
> "payload": [
> {
> "file": "string",
> "filetype": "string"
> }
> ]
> }

when i pass list of object from the frontend with the same format, i got Upload error: 404 Unprocessable Entity. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: You can't compose a model like that when using HTTP post, instead you'll have to handle each parameter yourself: `process_files(files: List[UploadFile], filetype: List[str])` should do what you want - i.e. you'll have to have multiple form fields with the same name in that case; uploading files through standard post forms doesn't work together with JSON bodies.